# insert datestamp if condition is satisfied

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I would like to insert datetime stamp into a variable once the if-condition is satisfied. But  I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: status in C:\wamp\www\business\edit_log_widget.php on line 55

The following is the php code:

```
<?php
    include 'scripts/init.php';
    include 'html/header.php';
    $page = 'servers';

    $id =$_SESSION['logid'];
    $query = "SELECT *FROM log WHERE logid = $id";
    $query_submit = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_submit);
?>

<div class="article">
    <h2><span>Edit Logs</span></h2>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <form action="" method="POST" >
    <p>
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td><label for="Task Name">Task Name:*</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="task_name" size="45" value="<?php echo $row['task_name'] ?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="description">Problem Description:*</label></td>
                <td><textarea name="description" cols="33" rows="10" ><?php echo $row['description'] ?></textarea></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td><label for="solution">Solution Description:*</label></td>
                <td><textarea name="solution" cols="33" rows="10" ><?php echo $row['solution'] ?></textarea></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td><label for="status">Status:*</label></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="Select2" name="status">
                        <option>-Select-</option>
                        <option>Resolved</option>
                        <option>Un-resolved</option>
                        <option>In-Progress</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </p>
    <p>
        <td><input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        <td><input id ="Clear and Restart" type ="reset" value= "Clear and Restart" /></td>
    </p>
    <?php 
        if($_POST['status']== 'Resolved')
        {
            $today = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d',date('Y-m-d')); // This is Line 55
        }

        if(isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['sucess']))
        {
            echo 'the log has been captured';
        }
        else
        {
            if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors)=== true)
            {
                //Update Log details
                $update_log = array(
                                'task_name'=>$_POST['task_name'],
                                'description' => $_POST['description'],
                                'solution' =>$_POST['solution'],
                                'status'=>$_POST['status'],
                                'closed_date'=>$today,
                                'userid' =>$_SESSION['userid']);
                update_log($update_log);
                //redirect
                header('Location: edit_log_widget.php?success');
                exit();
            }
            else if(empty($errors) === false)
            {
                //output errors if the errors array is not empty
                echo output($errors);
            }
        }
    ?>
    </form>  
    <?php
        include 'html/side_menu.php';
        include 'html/footer.php';
    ?>
```

Update: edit_log.php.

```
<?php
    include 'scripts/init.php';
    include 'html/header.php';
    $page = 'servers';

    $id = $_GET['logid'];
    $_SESSION['logid'] = $id;
    $query = "SELECT *FROM log WHERE logid = $id";
    $query_submit = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_submit);
?>

<div class="article">
    <h2><span>Edit Logs</span></h2>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <form action="edit_log_widget.php" method="POST" >
    <p>
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td><label for="Task Name">Task Name:*</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="task_name" size="45" value="<?php echo $row['task_name'] ?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="description">Problem Description:*</label></td>
                <td><textarea name="description" cols="33" rows="10" ><?php echo $row['description'] ?></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="solution">Solution Description:*</label></td>
                <td><textarea name="solution" cols="33" rows="10" ><?php echo $row['solution'] ?></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="status">Status:*</label></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="Select2" name="status">
                        <option>-Select-</option>
                        <option value="Resolved">Resolved</option>
                        <option value="Un-resolved">Un-resolved</option>
                        <option value="In-Progress">In-Progress</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </p>
    <p>
        <td><input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        <td><input id ="Clear and Restart" type ="reset" value= "Clear and Restart" /></td>
    </p>
</form>  
<?php
    include 'html/side_menu.php';
    include 'html/footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: What corresponds to line 55?

Comment: I identified it on the on the code.  its if($_POST['status']== 'Resolved')---Line 55
       {
        $today = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d',date('Y-m-d'));
        
       }

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved all the php to the top of the html form and now it works fine. Thanks guys for trying to help me out

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified any value to your options ;)

```
<option value="Resolved">Resolved</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST['status']
```

the entry status of the array $_POST is not defined

You are trying to access variables that are not yet set.

To avoid that you could check first, if the form was submitted before e.g.

```
<?php 
        if(!empty($_POST['Submit'])){

                    if($_POST['status']== 'Resolved')
                        {
                            $today = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d',date('Y-m-d')); // This is Line 55

                        }


                    if(isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['sucess']))
                        {
                            echo 'the log has been captured';
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors)=== true)
                                {
                                                                            //Update Log details
                                    $update_log = array(
                                    'task_name'=>$_POST['task_name'],
                                    'description' => $_POST['description'],
                                    'solution' =>$_POST['solution'],
                                    'status'=>$_POST['status'],
                                    'closed_date'=>$today,
                                    'userid' =>$_SESSION['userid']);


                                    update_log($update_log);
                                    //redirect
                                    header('Location: edit_log_widget.php?success');
                                    exit();

                                }
                            else if(empty($errors) === false)
                                {
                                    //output errors if the errors array is not empty
                                    echo output($errors);
                                }
                        }
                    }
            ?>
```

Comment: check if form was sent before

Comment: I think the form has been sent

Comment: after the form is sent you won't see the notice
"Notice: Undefined index: status" anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code is executed before the form has been submitted, and therefor $_POST['status'] has not yet been defined.

Comment: The above code is for edit_log_widget.php. The initial form is completed on edit_log.php, then through the <form action=""> its passed to edit_log_widget.php, therefore I think status should have a value before the php gets executed

Comment: How is it passed to edit_log_widget.php? Maybe there is something wrong there? I would use <form action="edit_log_widget.php" method="POST"> to pass the values, if I'm not missing anything here?

Comment: Yeah! thats how I pass it, I just didnt attach the code for edit_log.php. the above code is for edit_log_widget.php only

Comment: Could you attach the code for edit_log.php too, it would be easier to see if anything is wrong with passing the values.

Comment: Are you sure that you are sending a value from the select box? If you submit the form on edit_log.php, with the "-Select-"-option selected, the $_POST['status'] will not be defined, since there is no value in that option. If you submit the form from edit_log_widget.php, none of the options have values, and status will never be defined.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some html props, your `<option>` must have a the `value` prop like so:

```
<td>
   <select id="Select2" name="status">
      <option value="0">-Select-</option>
      <option value="1">Resolved</option>
      <option value="2">Un-resolved</option>
      <option value="3">In-Progress</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

You're getting that error because you're missing it on your first html snippet, while you have it on your second, so there's nothing for PHP to get